# How to assert an integer is within range by using Unittest in Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a file to validate the label

```
#configmanager.py

class FunctionNode(object):
    def __validate_func_label(self, func_label):
        pattern = re.compile('^fn[1-9][0-9]{0,1}$')
        if not pattern.match(func_label):
            raise Exception(
                f"Invalid value {func_label} for function label in function config.")
```

and I have to write a test case for it using Unit Testing. Test case will check if user enters `fn` is between 1 and 99, it will pass. Otherwise if `fn` out of range such as `fn0` or `fn100` then it fail. I writed a TestClass

```
#test__validate_func_label.py

import unittest
from configmanager import FunctionNode

class TestValidateFuncLabel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_fn_within_range(self):
        for i in range(1,99):
            self.assertEqual(fn(i),output[i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But I feel like I'm not on the right track.
Is there any way i can assert `fn` is within range from 1 to 99?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.assertTrue( 0<=y<=99)
```

where `y` is the value of `fn` you are  checking.

However, I don't understand how your question relates to your code. In your code, you assert that `fn(i)` has a certain value (taken from a list named `output` which is not elsewhere defined), where `i` takes each value  from 1 to 98.

But in  your question you ask about asserting that a value is between these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn

```
self.assertIn(fn, range(1, 100))
```